# How do I append a value to dict key? (AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append')

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, append, key

Say I have a dictionary with one key (and a value):

```
dict = {'key': '500'}.
```

Now I want to add a new value `'1000'` to the same key. However,

```
dict[key].append('1000')
```

just gives me `"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'".`

If I do

```
dict[key] = '1000'
```

it replaces the previous value.

I'm guessing I have to create a list as a value and somehow append that list as the key's value but I'm not sure how I would go about this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: yeah `dct = {'key': ['500']}.` to create a list-value. And don't use `dict` since it would mask the type.

Comment: What do you expect the result to look like exactly? `{'key': [500, 1000]}`…? Hint, HINT, **HINT**

Comment: To add to Jean, don't use `dict` as a variable name

Comment: retrieve the current value, store it in a list, put the list in the dict as new value.   `v = d['key']`  +  `d['key'] = [ v, '789']`

Comment: @internet_user so what? if the one value is a list it can hold plenty data ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the usage of a `defaultdict`  that instantiates an empty list when a key is missing.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d['key'].append(500)
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'key': [500]})
>>> d['key'].append(1000)
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'key': [500, 1000]})
```

I don't recommend having strings/integers as values and then switching to lists once you want to append to a field. Keep it consistent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and the other comments too, this was very helpful!