# Append string value to an existing key in dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, append

I am trying to append a value to a key that already exists in a dict.

I came across this SO link [How do I append a value to dict key? (AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49437153/how-do-i-append-a-value-to-dict-key-attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attrib) however in this particular case the values were integers while in my case the values are strings.

What I want is:

```
mydict = {'ADE':'AD', 'RS':'S'}
key1 = 'ADE'
value1 = 'AE'

if key1 in mydict:
    mydict[key1].append(value1)
else:
    mydict[key1] = value1
```

I want to append to `mydict['ADE']` so that it equals `['AD','AE']`.

However, that generates a `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'`

I even tried the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
mydict = {'ADE':'AD', 'RS':'S'}
for key, value in mydict.items():
    d[key] = value
```

`d` then = `defaultdict(list, {'ADE': 'AD', 'RS': 'S'})`

Then I run the following:

```
key1 = 'ADE'
value1 = 'AE'

if key1 in d:
    d[key1].append(value1)
else:
    d[key1] = value1
```

But I get the same error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'`

Comment: `defaultdict` only uses the default factory for a *missing* key, e.g. `d['ADE']` is already present so you just get the value `'AD'`. If you want all of the keys to be lists, change `{'ADE': 'AD', 'RS': 'S'}` to `{'ADE': ['AD'], 'RS': ['S']}`.

Comment: Oops. What a goof on my part. Thanks all it all makes sense now. Was trying to append to a string and not a list.

Answer (score 2):

`mydict[key1]` is a `str`ing (a `str` object - an object of class `str`). `mydict[key1].append(value1)` attempts to call the `append` method of this `str` object.

`str` objects do *not* have the `append` method, which is exactly what the error message is telling you: "'str' object has no attribute 'append'".

If you want to append data to something, use a collection, like a list:

```
mydict = {'ADE': ['AD'], 'RS': ['S']}

if key1 in mydict:
    mydict[key1].append(value1)
else:
    mydict[key1] = [value1]
```

Answer (score 2):

As the key `ADE` is present, the `list` factory is unused, and so the error becomes inevitable.

You may use the list factory at the very beginning, and so the `if .. in ..` is useless as the purpose of a `defaultdict` is to avoir checking that by yourself

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
mydict = {'ADE': 'AD', 'RS': 'S'}
for key, value in mydict.items():
    d[key].append(value)

key1 = 'ADE'
value1 = 'AE'
d[key1].append(value1)

print(d)  # defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'ADE': ['AD', 'AE'], 'RS': ['S']})
```

Answer (score -2):

what do you mean by append the value?
ADE is the key and AE is the value. are you trying to change the value to AD?
or are you trying to do something like AE+AD = AEAD and assign it to ADE key?
you question is not clear.

The error you are getting is becuase d[key1] is a string value. string type does not have append function to it.